# 3D Rotation Maths in Python

Tags: python, 3d, coordinates, trigonometry

I'm writing code to make a machine orient a cutting tool in angle of a given vector. I need to rotate the 3D vector coordinates about the Y axis, I've got the equation figured out, but the code just breaks when I use it. Let me show you.

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, i, j, k):
    self.i = i
    self.j = j
    self.k = k

v0 = Vector(0.7844645405527362, 0.19611613513818404, 0.5883484054145521)

def findB():
    if v0.i != 0:
        angle = atan(v0.i/v0.k)
    else:
        angle = 0
    print(angle, degrees(angle))  --> 0.92729... 53.13010...

    v1 = Vector(v0.i, v0.j, v0.k)
# this formula rotates the vector about the j axis (comparable to y axis rotation)
    v1.i = v0.i * cos(angle) - v0.k * sin(angle)
    v1.k = v0.k * cos(angle) + v0.i * sin(angle)
    return angle, v1

machine.b, v1 = findB()

print(v1.i, v1.j, v1.k) --> 1.1102230246251565e-16 0.19611613513818404 0.9805806756909203
```

I've tested that formula on a calculator and it rotates the coordinates correctly, I even hard coded the values to be:

```
v1.i = 0.784 * cos(0.927) - 0.588 * sin(0.927)
v1.k = 0.588 * cos(0.927) + 0.784 * sin(0.927)
```

Hard coding the values produces the correct result, but as soon as I use 'angle', v0.i and v0.k as the variables it gets v1.i incorrect. v1.i should be zero (or nearly zero from rounding). I've tested the same formula on a calculator and it works fine. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It is nearly zero, no?

Comment: You do realize that 1.1102230246251565e-16 is 0.00000000000000011102230246251565, which is quite close to zero? It's in scientific notation which may confuse.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm so sorry guys, how ignorant of me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd use `atan2` in `findB`, and question the current 0 test which looks like it should test v0.k

Comment: Indeed, I will be changing it to atan2. I just needed to get the proof of concept going first and happened to use atan. Thanks for the suggestion.